# how to merge keys with same value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

code;

```
    $all_tags = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $all_tags = array_merge($all_tags, explode(' ', $row['title']));
}
$all_tags = array_count_values($all_tags);
echo "<pre>";
arsort($all_tags);

foreach ($all_tags as $key => $val) {
  echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```

output;

```
fuups! = 7
401 = 5
Authorization = 5
Required = 5
, = 3
izle = 3
Error = 2
Server = 2
Internal = 2
500 = 2
Full = 1
MegaSinema.net = 1
Sinema = 1
Bad = 1
Request = 1
Film = 1
400 = 1
```

all i wanna do is merge 'keys' with same integer 'value'. example;

```
401 = 5
Authorization = 5
Required = 5
```

to

```
401 Authorization Required = 5
```

i don't know how could i do it. i tried a bunch of ways but i never let it work. thank you.

Comment: If you want an answer in MySQL, you'll have to explain the tables' structure and what the outcome of the query is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood you in the beginning. 
I think you could just save the objects in an array and implode them if needed.

```php
$out = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    if(array_key_exists($value, $out))
         $out[$value][] = $key;
    else
         $out[$value] = array($key);

// Then you could do
echo implode(" ", $out[5]); // Should output "401 Authorization Required"
```

Working example at http://codepad.org/MgLKXA75

Another option is to directly append it and trim the "extra" space at the end.

```php
$out = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    if(array_key_exists($value, $out))
         $out[$value] .= $key . ' ';
    else
         $out[$value] = $key . ' ';

// Then you could do
echo trim($out[5]); // Should output "401 Authorization Required"
```

Comment: okay, looks like its working just fine. but you only echo specified one with $out[5] but i want to echo them all. mm sorry for my bad english. i need to echo every key with same value not only $out[5]

Comment: Just go over the result and implode and echo all , check this :http://codepad.org/wKXCo3p0

Comment: alright it works very fine now. one more question, is this fastest way to do this? asking because i'll use this with lots of arrays

Comment: I don't know if its the fastest, only way to check is to do benchmarking vs. other methods, but its definitely simple enough and shouldn't cause any problems unless you have millions of keys in an array :) You could also append it directly to the string and trim empty spaces if needed (check the example) : http://codepad.org/CtRjRmjJ

Comment: weh! i will accept your answer but there is one more thing. i need to do a stop words filter too. could you help me with this :) ?

Comment: Is it part of the same thing? Usually when it comes to stop words you could just add an array of "bad words" and make sure its not there with in_array as follows: http://codepad.org/JSf6KtXT

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $data = array('fuups!' => '7','401' => '5','Authorization' => '5','Required' => '5',',' => '3','izle' => '3','Error' => '2','Server' => '2','Internal' => '2','500' => '2','Full' => '1','MegaSinema.net' => '1','Sinema' => '1','Bad' => '1','Request' => '1','Film' => '1','400' => '1');
    $rows = array();
    $values = array_values($data);
    asort($values);
    $highestVal = $values[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $highestVal; $i++) {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if ($i == $value) {
                $rows[$i] = $rows[$i] . " {$key}";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Working Example XD http://codepad.org/x9uHs1sp

EDIT----

To `echo` all keys, just replace `var_dump($rows)` with:

```
foreach ($rows as $key) {
    echo "{$key}<br />";
}
```

Comment: this works too but i think you limited loop with $i <= 7. how can i make it never ending loop? (i will limit with mysql query)

Comment: I updated it to get the highest value out of the array and loop up to that value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but I think you can try to create a hash table to handle this.

For example, if you insert above 3 items into the hash table and use '5' as the key, the first  item can be inserted correctly, and the other two should throw exceptions. You can catch the exception since it's excepted and append the values to the value of the first item. So the item in you hash table should be like:

key: 5
value: 401 Authorization Required

But you should make sure about the orders in the value.

Just my 2 cents, good luck!

Update:
If throwing exception is not acceptable, you can look-up a key in the hash table first, if the key doesn't exist then insert the key and value, if it already exists then append the value to existing item value.

Comment: Throwing an exception will let the operating system take over, this will take a lot of unnecessary time.